# Invalid data in objects created on stack C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

I couldn't really find any better title for this question.

I have three classes: `CheckBox`, `Button` and `Background`.

```
class CheckBox : public Component
{
private:
    Button m_button;
public:
    CheckBox(const Point &pos, int width, int height, std::string text);
    CheckBox();
};

CheckBox::CheckBox(const Point &pos, int width, int height, string text) : 
    Component(pos, width, height),
    m_button(Button(Point(width-height,0), new Background("button_bg_sample.png", true), new Background("button_bg_onclick_sample.png", true), height, height, 10, "")),
{

}


class Button : public Component
{
private:
    std::string m_text;
    Background* m_pBackground;
    Background* m_pBackgroundOnClick;
    int m_fontSize;
public:
    Button(const Point& pos, Background* pBg, Background* pBgOnClick, int width, int height, int fontSize, std::string title);
    ~Button();

};

Button::Button(const Point& pos, Background* pBg, Background* pBgOnClick, int width, int height, int fontSize, string title) : 
    Component(pos, width, height), 
    m_pBackground(pBg),
    m_pBackgroundOnClick(pBgOnClick),
    m_fontSize(fontSize),
    m_text(title)
{
}


class Background
{
private:
    std::string m_pFileName;
    bool m_bTiling;
    std::vector<unsigned char> m_pImageData;
    unsigned int m_width;
    unsigned int m_height;
    GLuint m_texture; 

    bool load(const std::string& pFileName);
public:
    Background(const std::string& pFileName, bool bTiling);
    ~Background();

    bool draw(const Point &pos, unsigned int width, unsigned int height);
    bool draw(const Point &pos);
};

Background::Background(const string& pFileName, bool bTiling) : 
    m_bTiling(bTiling), 
    m_pFileName(pFileName)
{
    load(pFileName);
}
```

So as you can see, `CheckBox` class includes `Button m_button` and `Button` class includes `Background* m_pBg`. In `Background` constructor I load image data and store it in `std::vector`, it doesn't really matter - I know it's working, because it was already checked.

When I create `CheckBox` object, the data inside it's `m_button` is corrupted. When I try to check what's inside image data in debug mode, I get information that it's empty and the file name of that background is `"Error reading characters in string"`. Though when I saw following step by step the code in debug mode, I've seen that the data was properly loaded inside constructor, but somehow when the object was created, data was already corrupted.

When I changed `m_button` field in `CheckBox` class to be created on a heap (pointer to `Button`, object created by using `new` operator) everything seems to be working just fine. Data is being loaded properly and remains like this.

Could anyone please explain me what can be the reason of such problem?

Comment: You don't even provide all the code, e.g. what if ~Button() destroys the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Button` which is created on stack in initialization list of `CheckBox`'s constructor is being copied to `m_button` field:

```
m_button = Button();
```

What default =operator is doing, is COPYING every field inside new created `Button` object to `m_button`:

```
m_button.height = b.height // Let's assume, that 'b' is the name of this new Button
m_button.width = b.width
m_button.name = b.name
...
```

Now what happens if you have a pointer `p1` which points to some object and you have the other pointer `p2` and you assign `p1` to `p2`?

```
int* p1 = new int(5);
int* p2 = p1;
```

Both pointers are now pointing to the same object! And the same thing happend to your `Background*`. You have two `Button`s which point to the same `Background` object somewhere in memory. But your second `Button` created in initializing list is being destroyed as it goes out of a scope and what PROBABLY (because I haven't seen destructor of your `Button` class) is happening, you are destroying the `Background` object in your `Button` destructor. That's why when you follow the code in debug mode you see properly created `Background`, but later it is being destroyed with the `Button` object.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not obeying [the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

The class `Button` manages memory itself, so when you create copies or make assignments, you'll likely run into trouble. I didn't dig in the code so can't say for sure this is the root (it is a problem nonetheless), but I'm pretty sure it is.

This could all be avoided if you used smart pointers instead of raw pointers to manage resources.